# Azure APIM Synthetic GraphQL is running resolvers for null fields

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-api-management

Currently I'm having an issue with optional fields in my schema triggering resolvers when null resulting in an error.

eg.

```
type Subscription {
subid: ID!
owningbusinessunit: BusinessUnit
}
```

If the foreign key for BusinessUnit is null my Subscription-owningbusinessunit resolver will still trigger when the field queried. At this point I can check if the parent key is null but there's nothing I can do in the resolver to stop execution of the resolver gracefully. If I `<set-url>null</set-url>` I'll get an error.

This seems like a very common scenario but I can't find any guidence online.

This is particularly dangerous when exposing ODATA queries using synthetic graphql e.g.

```
<set-url>@{
var id = context.GraphQL.Parent["_owningbusinessunit_value"].ToString();
return $"{{dataverse-backend}}/v9.2/businessunits({id})";
}
</set-url>
```

a null `_owningbusinessunit_value` results in the following ODATA query -

`......./v9.2/businessunits()` 
which will return all businessunits regardless if they relate to the parent.

I'm not sure how to resolve this, there doesn't seem to be any way to NOT run a resolver or end execution of the resolver early

Tried setting URL to `{}`, `{null}`, made sure all field names were consistant with the backend, and checked my data